# Oracle "PL/SQL TABLE" type to OracleDbType type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this Package:

```
create or replace PACKAGE pkg_stud_clm_data IS
TYPE t_test_clm_data_rec IS RECORD
(
            p_studentID     SYSTEM.STUDENT.student_id%TYPE,
            p_LastName      SYSTEM.STUDENT.last_name%tYPE,
            p_ModifiedDate  SYSTEM.STUDENT.modified_date%TYPE,
            p_ModifiedBy    SYSTEM.STUDENT.modified_by%TYPE,
            p_RegDate       SYSTEM.STUDENT.registration_date%TYPE,
            p_CreatedDate   SYSTEM.STUDENT.created_date%TYPE,
            p_CreatedBy     SYSTEM.STUDENT.created_by%TYPE,
      p_Zip           SYSTEM.student.zip%TYPE
);
TYPE t_test_clm_data_ref IS REF CURSOR
    RETURN t_test_clm_data_rec;
TYPE t_test_clm_data_tab IS TABLE OF t_test_clm_data_rec
    INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

PROCEDURE PROC_INS_STUDENT(io_table IN OUT t_test_clm_data_tab);
END pkg_stud_clm_data;
```

Which Im using inside with this package body:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY pkg_stud_clm_data IS
PROCEDURE PROC_INS_STUDENT 
(
    io_table IN OUT t_test_clm_data_tab
)
IS 
BEGIN
  FOR idx IN io_table.FIRST .. io_table.LAST LOOP
    INSERT INTO SYSTEM.STUDENT(
      STUDENT_ID,
            LAST_NAME,
            MODIFIED_DATE,
            MODIFIED_BY,
            REGISTRATION_DATE,
            CREATED_DATE,
            CREATED_BY,
      ZIP
      )
      VALUES
        (
            io_table(idx).p_studentID,
            io_table(idx).p_LastName,
            io_table(idx).p_ModifiedDate,
            io_table(idx).p_ModifiedBy,
            io_table(idx).p_RegDate,
            io_table(idx).p_CreatedDate,
            io_table(idx).p_CreatedBy,
      io_table(idx).p_Zip
        ); 
    END LOOP;
END PROC_INS_STUDENT;
END pkg_stud_clm_data;
```

Problem is, when Im trying to call it from .Net and create the input parameter for **io_table** which has a Data_Type of "PL/SQL TABLE" I'm unable to figure out the OracleDbType type to create that IN OUT parameter with.

I've tried using:

```
OracleDbType.RefCursor,
OracleDbType.Object,
OracleDbType.Array
```

But I keep getting errors as follows:
Array = `Invalid parameter binding Parameter name: "IO_TABLE"`
Object = `Invalid parameter binding Parameter name: "IO_TABLE"`

And for RefCursor which I believe I should be using I get:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROC_INS_STUDENT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that you can bind PL/SQL variables from .NET; You need to use SQL type array created as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_array AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

to be able to pass it from outside PL/SQL.

Alternativly write PL/SQL functions such as Add_element to add values one-by-one into global PL/SQL array. You can call them in the .Net loop. And then procedure which reads pre-populated global PL/SQL array.

Comment: It seems I've been doing a few things wrong on my .Net side I found one example of how they send in PL\SQL tables from .Net to insert records into the Oracle DB: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jan/o17odp-093600.html

I just haven't seen anything that would tell me whether its possible to send a whole table at once instead of a table per coloum